# How do you play audio from another object on trigger in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity and whenever I walk into a box trigger I want it to play audio from another objects audio source in the scene. How would I do that.

Comment: You work start by implementing exactly that behavior ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you need ?

Remember this code must go on the object that has the box trigger, and don't forget to set the correct parameters for on trigger to work (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.name == "WalkingObject")  //can also use other.tag
    {
        GameObject.Find("ObjectWithAudioSource").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
}
```

you can also store that Audio source in a variable like so

```
AudioSource audioSource;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.name == "YourObject")
        {
             audioSource = GameObject.Find("ObjectWithAudioSource").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        }
    }
```

Than if you need you can add .Play or whatever you need after it

more on audio source https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html

Also if you use OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) you may also need OnTriggerExit(Collider other), Which would stop the trigger executing (if you need it)
(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html)